# WebAPI - case of field's names in json result

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

1) I have a WebAPI method, which returns object `User`. All fields of this object in callback of ajax call starting with uppercase. I'm trying to achieve camelCase in result. I do not want to write  `[JsonProperty]` before each field, but `ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();` doesn't working properly. I can't understand why.
2) In class `UserList` (see below) i have a link to `User`. When i'm trying to return `UserList` or `User` as a result of WebAPI method i'm getting an error about "self referencing loop". But i've written in configuration
`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` - why it's not working? And i do not want to write `[JsonIgnore]` in every such case.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
    }
}
```

Returning `User` object from controller:

```
var user = Data.GetUserByUserName(userName);

return Json<object>(new
        {
            success = true,
            user = user
        });
```

User class:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<UserList> UserLists { get; set; }

    public string AvatarFileID { get; set; }
    public int? AvatarFileProviderID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your 1st question is to simply return the object and not Json (or even more correctly - return a HttpResponse with the object included)

The answer to the second question: do not send your original models to the client, use ViewModels instead and pass only the properties that are needed (for example, in the front-end you may need only the users' names, and not the whole user objects)

Comment: About second question: Model contains only needed data in this case... I think it's not the better solution to duplicate class only to get separate viewmodel. And anyway serializing do not works properly.

Comment: The second proble are gone too, when i've changed json<object> to simply returning object.